# Sum the values of multiple entries into one field

Tags: mysql

In the MySQL database of a user has 3 fields assigned to him:

user_id
meta_key
meta_value

```
user_id = '297' 
meta_key = 'qty' 
meta_value = '1'
```

The problem is that when this user, let's say purchase another product, it wrongly added **another** 3 fields:

```
user_id = '297'  
meta_key = 'qty'  
meta_value = '1'
```

instead of just updating 'qty' with an increment value to '2'.
 So my database is filled with 3 or 4 duplicate entries, each one with a qty value of 1, instead of one field with the sum of all qty together.

I have since fixed the error causing this, but I now need to fix the database as well.

Image of the structure: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGVVq.png

I would like to know if there's a query that will SUM all the duplicate 'qty' values into one.

Comment: Do you want a query that will sum the duplicates, or do you want to fix the code that incorrectly added another row?

Comment: I just want the query that will sum the duplicates.  I have already fixed the code causing it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do it:

```
UPDATE theTable t
JOIN (SELECT user_id, meta_key, SUM(meta_value) meta_value_sum
      FROM theTable
      GROUP BY user_id, meta_key) t1
ON t.user_id = t1.user_id AND t.meta_key = t1.meta_key
SET t1.meta_value = meta_value_sum
```

Then remove all the duplicate records with:

```
ALTER TABLE IGNORE theTable ADD UNIQUE INDEX (user_id, meta_key)
```

Comment: Sorry Barmar, i forgot to mention the main table is called wp_usermeta  Is it possible to modify your query to pinpoint it to run on that table?

Comment: The answer is the same no matter what the name of the table is.

Comment: I'm sorry, but if you can't see how to replace `theTable` with `wp_usermeta` by yourself, you're hopeless and not worth my time to help.

Answer (score 0):

#### Select summed `meta_value`s

```
SELECT SUM(meta_value) FROM t1 WHERE meta_key = 'qty'
GROUP BY user_id
```

You can then delete all `qty` rows and insert these again with the correct summed value.

#### Upsert query

Make `user_id`, `meta_key` a `UNIQUE KEY`.  Then you can use this query to update the sum:

```
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES (297, 'qty', 1)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE meta_value = meta_value + 1
```